# How to call function with identical params?

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to call a grandparent's function.

For this reason, I need to create the same function in the parent-class.

This is my granparent's code:

```
class GP{
    public function validate(&$data, $source, $operationData=null){
        ...
    }
}
```

This is my child's call:

```
class child{
    public function doSth(){
        parent::validate(array(...), "user", true);
    }
}
```

In order to reach the grandparent's function, the parent uses this code:

```
class parent{
    protected function validate(&$data, $source, $operationData=null){
        return parent::validate($data, $source, $operationData);
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

When I change the parameters of the function, I need to change them in every single child-class too.

Is there a more efficient way for my parent-class, so I don't need to change anything there?

Comment: Why can't you just call the GP's method just like that?

Comment: why are you passing `$data` as reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `public` modifier on the method in the grandparent class, your child (and grandchild, and great-grandchild, etc.) classes will inherit this method. So, there is no need to write this:

```
protected function validate(&$data, $source, $operationData=null){
    return parent::validate($data, $source, $operationData);
}
```

Remove this declaration, and any sub-class of `GP` will be able to call `validate()` on the `GP` class.

For a short example, consider the following code:

```
class GP {
    public function foo() { echo 'Hello, world!'; }
}
class P extends GP {}
class C extends P {
    public function call_foo() {
        $this->foo();
    }
}
```

With an object of the child class:

```
$o = new C;
```

You can call the `foo()` method on the object:

```
$o->foo();
```

Or within the class:

```
$o->call_foo();
```

Comment: o_O I didn't know that ... and that makes sense! Seems that I have to rewrite some code now :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write parameters,  you can get all passed parameters by func_get_args () or get one parameter by func_get_arg (number)

And can pass them with:
$parent_class=get_parent_class($this); call_user_func_array(array($parent_class, 'walk'), $args);

Comment: That's true, I can get the parameters inside the parent as an array. But I can't pass them forward to the grandparent

Comment: This is also an expensive operation.